# Communication between Raspberry Pi 3 and PIC microcontroller

Tags: raspberry-pi

I am working on Raspberry Pi 3 board to communicate with a PIC micro controller through UART pins  but the RX is shorted to ground and TX is shorted to 3.3V supply. How to make the TX and RX pins to communicate with the micro controller through UART?

Comment: Did you try the documentation? https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/uart.md A quick DuckDuckGo search yields tons of results for 'raspberry pi uart.'

Comment: Lots more info needed. "*the RX is shorted to ground and TX is shorted to 3.3V*" (a) Whose Rx - RPi or PIC? (b) How do you know it is "*shorted* to ground"? (c) Whose Tx - RPi or PIC? (d) How do you know it is "*shorted* to 3.3V"? (e) Which parts of the design are under your control and can be changed - RPi only? PIC only? Both? Neither, only the connections between them? (f) Please give some information about your experience level with digital electronics design, UART, RPi and whichever PIC you are using? (g) What test equipment (and experience using it) do you have?

Comment: Note to other readers: Same question has been duplicated on [edaboard.com](http://www.edaboard.com/showthread.php?t=372041) so an answer might be given there first.

Answer (score 1):

If your RX and TX pins are shorted to other nodes, like power and ground, then you have a faulty board.  The answer is therefore to repair or replace the board.

For normal logic-level UART signals, the idle level is high, which is apparently 3.3 V in your case.  Note that this is different from RS-232, which is what PC COM ports use.  Not only is the signal inverted, but the voltage levels are quite different.

UART logic signals directly connected to the TX and RX lines of a PC COM port won't work.  You need something that does the conversion in-between.  There are chips intended for exactly that.  There is also my ready-made [RSLink2](http://www.embedinc.com/products/rslink2) product that brings out the lines on convenient connectors.